# How to get the params from an http requests when unit testing in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-jasmine

I have defined a method for my controller, like

```
$scope.submitForm = ( username, password ) =>{
    $http({ 
        method: 'post',
        url: 'balabala',
        params: {username, password}
    }).success( res => { /* */ } );
}
```

My test specs look like:

```
descript('myController', () => {
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    let controller, httpBackend, http, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(($controller, $httpBackend, $http, $scope) => {
        scope = $scope.$new();
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        http = $http;
        controller = $controller;

        httpBackend.when('POST', '/login')
            .respon({
                result: 'ok'
            });
    }));

    it('should POST login', () => {
        httpBackend.expectPOST('/login');
        const myController = controller('myController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $http: http
        });
        scope.submitForm();
        httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

How can I make sure that `username` and `password` have been posted?

//EDIT:
How do I assess the body of POST request?

```
const data = { foo: "1", bar: { x: "2" } };

httpBackend.expectPOST('http://example.com').respond((method, url, data, headers, params) => {
    console.log(method, url, data, headers, params);
});

http({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    data
});
```

The output is:

> 'POST', 'http://example.com', 'foo=1&bar=2', Object{Accept: 'application/js
>   on, text/plain, */*', Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=u
>   tf-8'}, undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a response value associated to post i.e

```
httpBackend.expectPOST('/login').respond({success:true});
```

And don't use when because expectPost will make sure that you are calling that post method if not it will throw an error if you are getting no errors then assume that post method has been called.

```
$httpBackend .whenGET('/testpath/testurl/z/values?max=10&min=1').respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {

// params will be {
//   max: 10,
//   min: 1
// }
```

});

Comment: Do you know how to get params and body when using httpBackend?

Comment: One question,  How do I assess the body of POST request? I have edited my question..

Comment: you can't do directly you need to have a get call.

Comment: get call? what is it?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using an old version of angular 1.2.6

Comment: nope you need to make an http get call on the same url then you can check whether your data is there or not

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. Can you please write it down?